Integration by part in $\mathbb{R}^n$
I am reading the following argument from this book. In the very last equality, clearly integration by parts is used. I am however confused on why no "boundary" term is there (or integration by parts is allowed), Nor is $w$ taken to be in $W_0^{1,2} (\mathbb{R}^n)$. Any help?


Notice that $u\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ so it and its 1st derivatives must decay to zero as $|x|\to 0$

This is not integration by parts but the actual definition of the weak/distributional Laplace operator (similar to the definition of weak derivatives by the integration by parts formula). That is,
$z \in L^1_{loc}$ is the weak Laplacian of $u\in H^1$, if and only if
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d} z \cdot \phi \ dx = -\int_{\mathbb R^d} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi \ dx \quad \forall \phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d).
$$
In the question, this identity is proven to be valid for all functions in $W^{1,2}$, which is more than necessary to invoke the definition.
